# Would there be any issue checking URL status every X seconds?

Tags: javascript, xmlhttprequest, setinterval

So we have a logic whereby we will check the status of a URL every 15 seconds like so:

```
const http = new XMLHttpRequest();
const alive = (url) => {
  http.open("HEAD", url, false);
  http.send();
  return http.status !== 404;
};
```

This url is scheduled to be working at a certain time of the day for a period of time only and our app will have to detect when it has returned `200`. Once it does, we'll display an iframe that has the `url` content (and also clear the interval). So whenever it's still returning a `404`, we will display an "upcoming" image instead.

Is it okay to keep doing this check? Won't we encounter too many requests error on the url at some point? Realise that we may not be able to have control on the server for that url. Let's say about 1000 people will be accessing the page that does the checking. Some of them may visit the page earlier and stay there. The page will start doing this check every 15 seconds up until the `url` becomes alive (which can take hours after the moment they land on the page).

Comment: What technology are you using to run your back end?

Comment: We are using node.js.

Comment: to answer if it's too frequent or not, you'd really have to know what (if any) mechanisms they have in place to prevent bots/scripts from polling the site, and at what frequency they allow it. is it too frequent?  probably not for most websites, but is it also possible that it could be shut down for pinging the site too frequently?  yes, depending on how it's being run and what measures are in place to protect from this sort of activity.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To determine whether or not something is alive, you'll probably want to return `http.status === 200` instead. This means if say there's an internal server error for example, an error 500, then it's assumed it is not alive.

For a polling approach, any interval *can* be too frequent if you have lots of users.

Your best bet for scalability is to have a socket-based system for communication. As you mentioned, you are using node.js. You can look into using [socket.io](https://www.npmjs.com/package/socket.io). When you go "live" then you can just emit an event to all connected clients.

Comment: It would be better to check for any `2xx` status code.  Also, Socket.IO isn't required for one-way communication.  It would be easier to use Server-Sent Events/EventSource.

Comment: Correct about the 2xx status code. The only way you'd be able to check for changes as to whether they are live would be a polling approach if you didn't use sockets.

Comment: No, that's not true.  As I said, you can use server-sent events.  https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Server-sent_events/Using_server-sent_events

Comment: Interesting, I learned something new! It's a very seldom used thing that I'm sure most are unaware of! Thanks.